# JFreeChart Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

Recently I tried using the JFreeChart library.

I could find some demos over the internet. A demo for Stacked Bar Chart displays the following (exclude the red circular marks).
[image]

Is there a way I can modify the labels marked using red? And is it possible to create multi-labeled bars, something like this:

[image]

Comment: +1 for effort with paiting,

Comment: lol, Or else, more will be needed to explain the same.

Comment: Take a look at the [Demo App](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) it contains loads of examples

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18920815/1031945