# Usage of DatasetUtilities.createCategoryDataset in jfreechart in java

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am creating a Stack Bar chart with ApplicationName on x axis and UserName on Y axis. I am using:

```
CategoryDataset stackDataset =  DatasetUtilities.createCategoryDataset("Users","App", double[][]data);
```

It populates the StackBarchart labelling User1, User2 ,User3 on Y axis and similarly App1, App2 etc on X-axis.

Problem: I have an arraylist of userName and applicationName like:

```
userName = [Max, John,Willy]
appname =[Google, Fb, Twitter]
```

And these names i have to populate instead of user1 or app1. I have searched something to do this but i am unable to implement this . The code used will be

```
CategoryDataset stackDataset = createCategoryDataset(java.lang.Comparable[] rowKeys, java.lang.Comparable[] columnKeys, double[][] data)
```

Any help will be appericiable.

Answer (score 4):

There is a version of [CategoryDataset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/CategoryDataset.html) that accepts arrays as a parameter, your call shold look like this

```java
    String[] userName = new String[] {"Max", "John","Willy"};
    String[] appname =new String[] {"Google", "Fb", "Twitter"};
    double[][] data = new double[][] {{2,5,3},{2,6,7},{3,5,6}};
    return DatasetUtilities.createCategoryDataset(userName,appname,data);
```

[image]

If you are user JFreeChart 1.0.14 `createCategoryDataset` is an overloaded method:

[image]

You need to use this set of parameters

```java
public static CategoryDataset createCategoryDataset(Comparable[] rowKeys,
    Comparable[] columnKeys, double[][] data)
```

Remember that `String` implements `Comparable<String>` so you can use a `String[]`

Comment: i have dataset like this only as you have done but it is saying that createCategoryDataset(String, string, double[][]) instead of  createCategoryDataset(String[], String[], double[][])